# Recommendations for migrating away from Veracity?

Tags: version-control, dvcs, version-control-migration, veracity

Any recommendations on improvements to my approach for migration away from Veracity?

## Background:

I finally hit my limit with [Veracity](http://veracity-scm.com/):

1. all attempted commits (after 6 months of use) suddenly give "`Error 101 (sqlite): sg_wc_db:tbl_gid can't find alias 7033.`" (I searched - couldn't find help on this anywhere).
2. Veracity 2.5 (the latest version) is over 4.5 years old at the time of this latest edit.
3. "Questions" link at http://veracity-scm.com/qa (which was formerly useful) now <strike>gives a 404</strike> simply redirects back to the home page.
4. The online community surrounding Veracity seems too small, and http://sourcegear.com/ seems focused on its non-open source version control systems, instead.

In summary, I've lost confidence in Veracity to manage my significant bits.

## Extraction Approach I Used (admittedly low-tech):

1. used "`vv fast-export`" to get a fast-import stream for my new DVCS.  This preserved the source history.
2. Manually copied out my Veracity wiki pages to another existing wiki I use.
3. (Most tediously) Pored over my Veracity Work Items to make sure I didn't lose information critical to my project.

## Conclusion:

I was originally seduced by the integrated wiki & bug tracking features of Veracity.  I now regret that choice, and have moved back to a more mainstream DVCS option.

Comment: Yes, I tried to use it yesterday, and it doesn't work on El Capitan. Seems like a good abandoned project.

Answer (score 3):

I've used fossil (http://fossil-scm.org) for at one small project.

It's a little different from almost everything else it seems. That said I would still classify it as developer-friendly. The biggest issue I found when I evaluated it was that it did not have mature ide-integration at that time.